# WooCommerce search not working (Revo theme)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Please i just setup a woocommerce website and i've uploaded a lot of products, but unfortunately i discovered the the search bar on the webpage is not spooling any result. I've conducted a series of search intentionally using a product am sure is on the website, yet the search result is bringing nothing. I am using Revo theme, but could this be an issue with the theme am using. Please guys i seriously need your help on this. Your suggestion to get this fix is very important to me.

thanks in anticipation.

Comment: could you post more details, like the what does the output of ajax request?

Comment: Can you put the `search.php` file, please?

Comment: This is what is in the searchform.php file:



<form role="search" method="get" class="form-search searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
  <label class="hide"></label>
  <input type="text" value="<?php if (is_search()) { echo get_search_query(); } ?>" name="s" class="search-query" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'revo' ) ?>">
  <button type="submit" class="fa fa-search button-search-pro form-button"></button>
</form>